# What characters can be used in an objective-c method?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

What characters can use use in an objective-c method?

I know that you can use the Latin alphabet as well as + - ( ) : ; *, where the symbols are reserved. But are there other characters you can use? Numbers? Non-latin characters? Other symbols like = . * etc.

Comment: used in *what*?  variable or class names?

Comment: you can simply put any character in the method name and see if it compiles.